# In jenkins how to restrict users to select first default element with other options in extended choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins job with multi select extended choice parameter. There are list of elements in a parameter. So, my requirement is I want to allow users to select multiple parameters excluding first element in a parameter. Means user should not able to select first element with other elements in a parameters. I am using jenkinsfile to create parameter.

[image]

Like shown above, users should not able to select 'None' with any other element in a parameter. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with just `Extended choice parameter`. As a workaround, you can add two parameters. The first parameter to check whether it's None or not, if not you can bring up the second parameter. You can use the [Active Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) for this.

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT',
            description: 'Select a choice',
            filterLength: 1,
            name: 'choice1',
            referencedParameters: 'CHOICE',
            script: [$class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [], 
                    sandbox: true, 
                    script: """
                        if (CHOICE == 'Yes') { 
                            return['Item1','Item2','Item3']
                        }
                        else {
                            return[]
                        }
                    """.stripIndent()
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'CHOICE', description: "Do you have any choices?", choices: ["Yes", "None"])
    }
    stages {
        stage("Run Tests") {
            steps {
                sh "echo SUCCESS on ${params.CHOICE}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, there will be multiple parameters and I want to allow user to select multiple parameters at once except None

Comment: @svw1105 I think you didn't get my point. Check the updated answer with a working Pipeline.